# Does hashtable size depends upon length of key?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

What i know,

1. Hashtable size depends on load factor.
2. It must be largest prime number, and use that prime number as the
   modulo value in hash function.
3. Prime number must not be too close to power of 2 and power of 10.

Doubt I am having,

1. **Does size of hashtable depends on length of key?**

Following paragraph from the book Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen.
Does n=2000 mean length of string or number of element which will be store in hash table?

> Good values for m are primes not too close to exact powers of 2. For
>   example, suppose we wish to allocate a hash table, with collisions
>   resolved by chaining, to hold roughly n = 2000 character strings,
>   where a character has 8 bits. We don't mind examining an average of 3
>   elements in an unsuccessful search, so we allocate a hash table of
>   size m = 701. The number 701 is chosen because it is a prime near  =
>   2000/3 but not near any power of 2. Treating each key k as an integer,
>   our hash function would be
>
> h(k) = k mod 701 .

Can somebody explain it>

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? Number of buckets? Avg. number of elements per bucket? Avg. chain length? Number of bytes used in RAM by "everything" related to the table?

Comment: I do not understand you. I asked "What do you mean by 'size'", obviously in regards to your question "Does sze of..." and you answered "length of the key"... does not compute.

Comment: simple size=Number of buckets and does number of buckets depends on length of given string key :)

Comment: No, why would it? In all honesty, maybe you're best served by just playing with a small example (with pen&paper) and see what happens. It looks like you're getting a bit caught up in the theoretical stuff. ;)

Comment: Hash table sizes don't actually need to be prime or away from powers of two. Most common implementations do this, but theoretically it's not strictly required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general overview of the tradeoff with hash tables.
Suppose you have a hash table with `m` buckets with chains storing a total of `n` objects.

If you store only references to objects, the total memory consumed is `O (m + n)`.

Now, suppose that, for an average object, its size is `s`, it takes `O (s)` time to compute its hash once, and `O (s)` to compare two such objects.
Consider an operation checking whether an object is present in the hash table.
The bucket will have `n / m` elements on average, so the operation will take `O (s n / m)` time.

So, the tradeoff is this: when you increase the number of buckets `m`, you increase memory consumption but decrease average time for a single operation.

---

For the original question - *Does size of hashtable depends on length of key?* - No, it should not, at least not directly.

The paragraph you cite only mentions the strings as an example of an object to store in a hash table.
One mentioned property is that they are 8-bit character strings.
The other is that "*We don't mind examining an average of 3 elements in an unsuccessful search*".
And that wraps the properties of the stored object into the form: how many elements on average do we want to place in a single bucket?
The length of strings themselves is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: so if for n=10^5 if  i do 10^5/3 will be size of hash table with average 3 element in a single bucket

Comment: @sunilsarode Yes, exactly. Every element has to go into exactly one bucket. When there are 10^5 elements but 10^5/3 buckets, it's three elements per bucket on average.

Answer (score 0):

(2) and (3) are false. It is common for a hash table with `2^n` buckets ([ref](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/speeding-up-khash-with-a-power-of-2-bucket-count/)) as long as you use the right hash function. On (1), the memory a hash table takes equals the number of buckets times the length of key. Note that for string keys, we usually keep pointers to strings, not the strings themselves, so the length of key is the length of a pointer, which is 8 bytes on 64-bit machines.

Comment: can you please explain more and also does  n=2000 mean number of element which will be store in hash table?

Comment: Your quote is confusing. I am not sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmic-wise, No! 
The length of the key is irrelevant here.
Moreover, the key itself is not important, what's important is the number of different keys you predict you'll have.

Implementation-wise, Yes! Since you must save the key itself in your hashtable, it reflects on its size.

For your second question, 'n' means the number of different keys to hold.

Comment: so hash table will have size=701 and it will have n=2000 number of different key in the form of chaining